# What is the browsing context of a web component?

Tags: html, web-component

If I have a web component B, and I use/run it inside it a page A, which of the following is true:

1. A and B share the same [browsing context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Browsing_context)
2. B is running in a different/independent browsing context
3. Something else (please explain)

Answer (score 0):

The context is the same.

If you are using Shadow DOM in component B then A and the shadow Root of B are different DOM trees. But the context is still the same.

Component B can do anything it wants to Page A and page A can, within certain limitations to anything it wants with the inner DOM elements of B. (Unless you call `this.attachShadow({mode: 'closed'});`